# Spock mocks for Akka's ActorRef

Tags: scala, groovy, akka, spock

I've tried to make an Spock test for a class, where i need to check that it sends a message to actor (say `statActor`). I know that Akka have special library for integration test, but seems that it's too much for very simple test. So, i've tried:

```
setup:
def myActor = Mock(ActorRef)
myService.statActor = myActor
when:
myService.startStats()
then:
1 * myActor.tell(_)
```

Target method looks like:

```
void startStats() {
    Date x = null
    // prepare some data, fill x with required value
    this.statActor.tell(x)
}
```

I thought that Spock will create mock with a method `tell`. But after running this test i'm getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: akka.actor.ActorRef$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$80b97938 cannot be cast to akka.actor.ScalaActorRef
    at akka.actor.ActorRef.tell(ActorRef.scala:95)
    at com.example.MyService.startStats(MyService.groovy:32)
```

Why it's calling real `ActorRef` implementation? Some kind of incompatibility with Scala? Is there any way to make mock for such class?

Comment: "but seems that it's too much for very simple test" <-- may I ask how this conclusion is made, especially considering that the mocking you've tried didn't work out?

Comment: @ViktorKlang because one line `def actor = Mock(ActorRef)` is less that few dozen of lines required for `testkit`. I mean it can make mock for other objects, works fine and really easy to use

Comment: @paradigmatic yes, i know. probably I'm asking hard questions, but what can I do here? :(

Answer (score 20):

The only supported way to mock an ActorRef is by creating a TestProbe:

```
// "system" is an ActorSystem
final TestProbe probe = TestProbe.apply(system);
final ActorRef mock = probe.ref;
```

It does not get easier or simpler than this.

Comment: Thanks. How I can test that `.tell()` is called for this actor, with a value that i can test as well?

Comment: There plenty of methods for asserting message reception on a probe, listed on http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/testkit/TestProbe.html

Comment: Oh, I was sure that it's the same as `TestActorRef`

Comment: @Roland Kuhn Actually i've asked about using it with Spock. As I understand, you mean that there is not way to use standard Spock mocks for Akka, right?

Comment: @Igor: If you want to write your own testkit for Akka, feel free.

Answer (score 2):

In specs2 you can do:

```
val mockedActorRef = spy(TestProbe().ref)
```

Then use it as normal.